# Issues with Web Speech API in Android Chrome

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, webspeech-api, webkitspeechrecognition

I'm trying to make use of the [SpeechRecognition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition) interface of the [Web Speech API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API). It works fine on the desktop version of Chrome but I can't get it to detect any audio on the Android version. After failing to get my own code to work I tested [this demo](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html) as well as [this other demo](https://mdn.github.io/web-speech-api/speech-color-changer/) on two different Android devices (one running LineageOS Nougat, one running LineageOS Pie, both with Chrome 79) but neither demo worked on either device.

I'm not sure what's wrong here... can anyone else get these demos working on Android? I am serving my test page over https and I can record audio from the microhpone on these devices just fine using [navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) so it doesn't seem to be a hardware, permission, or security issue.

The specific symptoms I'm seeing are as follows:

- The [`start`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition/start_event) event fires after initially starting the recognition as expected but the subsequent [`audiostart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition/audiostart_event),[`soundstart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition/soundstart_event), [`speechstart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition/speechstart_event) and [`result`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition/result_event) events which *should* follow it never do.
- Attempting to call [`SpeechRecognition.stop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition/stop) seems to have no effect — the [end](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition/end_event) event does not get fired. Calling [`SpeechRecognition.start`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition/start) after a stop attempt throws **Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'start' on 'SpeechRecognition': recognition has already started.**
- Calling [`SpeechRecognition.abort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition/abort) does fire the `end` event and allows the recognition to be restarted.

Here's some test code based on the [example from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API/Using_the_Web_Speech_API).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title> Web Speech API Test </title>
    <style>
      * { box-sizing: border-box; }

      html {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }

      body {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: 1fr 10fr 1fr;
        font-family: sans-serif;
      }

      h1 {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0.5rem;
        background-color: dodgerblue;
        text-align: center;
      }

      #output {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0.5em;
        border: 0;
        background-color: transparent;
      }

      #start {
        display: block;
        background-color: dodgerblue;
        border: 0;
        color: navy;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 1.2em;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> Web Speech API Test </h1>
    <textarea id="output"></textarea>
    <button id="start"> START </button>
    <script>
      let SpeechRecognition = window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
      let SpeechGrammarList = window.SpeechGrammarList || window.webkitSpeechGrammarList;
      let SpeechRecognitionEvent = window.SpeechRecognitionEvent || window.webkitSpeechRecognitionEvent;

      let grammar = '#JSGF V1.0; grammar colors; public <color> = aqua | azure | beige | bisque | black | blue | brown | chocolate | coral | crimson | cyan | fuchsia | ghostwhite | gold | goldenrod | gray | green | indigo | ivory | khaki | lavender | lime | linen | magenta | maroon | moccasin | navy | olive | orange | orchid | peru | pink | plum | purple | red | salmon | sienna | silver | snow | tan | teal | thistle | tomato | turquoise | violet | white | yellow ;';

      let recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
      let speechRecognitionList = new SpeechGrammarList();
      speechRecognitionList.addFromString(grammar, 1);

      recognition.grammars = speechRecognitionList;
      recognition.continuous = false;
      recognition.lang = 'en-US';
      recognition.interimResults = false;
      recognition.maxAlternatives = 1;

      let startButton = document.getElementById('start');
      let output = document.getElementById('output');
      output.value += 'Initializing...';

      let listening = false;

      startButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
        if (listening == false) {
          recognition.start();
          startButton.innerHTML = 'STOP';
          listening = true;
        } else {
      //    recognition.stop();
          recognition.abort();
        }
      });

      console.dir(recognition);
      output.value += 'ready.';

      recognition.onstart = event => {
        output.value += '\nRecognition started';
      };

      recognition.onaudiostart = event => {
        output.value += '\nAudio started';
      };

      recognition.onsoundstart = event => {
        output.value += '\nSound started';
      };

      recognition.onspeechstart = event => {
        output.value += '\nSpeech started';
      };

      recognition.onspeechend = event => {
        output.value += '\nSpeech ended';
        recognition.stop();
      };

      recognition.onsoundend = event => {
        output.value += '\nSound ended';
      };

      recognition.onaudioend = event => {
        output.value += '\nAudio ended';
      };

      recognition.onend = event => {
        output.value += '\nRecognition stopped';
        startButton.innerHTML = 'START';
        listening = false;
      };

      recognition.onresult = event => {
        let color = event.results[0][0].transcript;
        let confidence = event.results[0][0].confidence;
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
        output.value += '\nResult recieved: ' + color;
        output.value += '\nConfidence: ' + confidence;
      };

      recognition.onnomatch = event => {
        output.value += '\nColor not recognised';
      };

      recognition.onerror = event => {
        output.value += '\nERROR: ' + event.error;
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas as to what the problem could be would be appreciated.

**UPDATE 2021-01-08:**

I modified the example code so that it outputs log messages to a `textarea` element instead of the console in order to eliminate the need for remote debugging. I also published a [live version](https://bes.works/dev/test/webspeech) on my domain. I then tested it using Chrome Canary 89 on LineageOS Oreo and found that it still did not work there. However, I then found that this example DOES work perfectly on a Razer Phone running it's official version of Android Pie and Chrome 87! So it would seem that my WebSpeech implementation is fine and possibly there is some other issue with LineageOS that has existed for multiple versions.

This question has recieved a fair number of views so I imagine others must be having similar issues. To those people, I suggest you try the live test  on few different devices and report your findings back here. Maybe we can narrow down the conditions that are causing it to fail on some devices but not others. Possibly this has nothing to do with LineageOS at all but is another issue altogether.

Comment: Just want to add that I also tried the above test code in Chrome Canary 82 with the same failing results.

Answer (score 1):

The Web Speech API on Android uses a third-party service that is usually implemented by Google (Play Services) and/or the manufacturer (e.g. Samsung). Most likely this service is missing or disabled in LineageOS since it usually connects to a cloud server for transcription.

Comment: That does seem like a very likely scenario. Makes me curious if installing a larger package from https://opengapps.org/ would help. I usually install the pico package on my devices which is pretty minimal.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no experience yet with that but would be interested in the result ^^. I think I've seen people with LineageOS that had it working.

Comment: Well right now I'm to busy with work to be messing with my phone but I'll definitely post the results if/when I get around to trying it. These comments alone might spur somebody else to give it shot before me though. I'll definitely accept your answer if we can prove that this is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You control the recognition object via the variable "listening", so please set "listening" to false, after recognition.stop().

```
recognition.onspeechend = event => {
    console.log('speechend');
    recognition.stop();
    listening = false;
};
```

Comment: This is a helpful tweak to the example code but does not solve the root issue here which is that the speech recognition does not successfully start. I have updated the original post with some new example code and test results.